# can't convert Fixnum into String on mongoid model save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Am using the save option on mongoid on ruby on rails, its throwing me an error

```
  can't convert Fixnum into String
```

my model file are

product.rb

```
 class Product

   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Timestamps
   include Mongoid::Versioning


   field :product_role, :type => String
   field :status_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId
   field :status_name,type: String
 end
```

status.rb

```
 class Status 

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  index :name => 1

 end
```

controller code is

```
        product_id = "523741002a6c6e8d1a000002",
        status_name = "Pending Review"
        product_detail_status = Product.where(id:product_id).first
        status = Status.where(name:status_name).first
        puts "##############"
        puts product_detail_status.id.to_s
        puts status.name.to_s
        puts status.id.to_s
        puts "##############"
        product_detail_status.status_name = status.name.to_s
        product_detail_status.status_id = status.id
        product_detail_status.save
```

i can able to view the values in puts, but its not saving by the way its throwing error on
 product_detail_status.save as  "can't convert Fixnum into String"

```
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 657ms

TypeError - can't convert Fixnum into String:
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/versioning.rb:53:in `revise'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in          `                
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:130:in `run_callbacks'
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:24:in `prepare'
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:45:in `persist'
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:145:in `update'
mongoid (3.1.4) lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:82:in `save'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Try with product_detail_status.status_id = status.id.to_s before saving the product_detail_status

Comment: @BachanSmruty i tried, still i got the same error

Comment: Information is too few. Please provide full stack error output.

Comment: How are you getting a [String in the `version` field](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/3.1.0-stable/lib/mongoid/versioning.rb#L53) when it is [supposed to be an integer](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/3.1.0-stable/lib/mongoid/versioning.rb#L11)?

Comment: @muistooshort can you explain my error, am new to this mongoid

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are getting that error, but a better approach may be to use [relations](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html) instead of manually adding a status_id and status_name to the product model

```
 class Product

   include Mongoid::Document 

   field :product_role, :type => String
   has_one :status
 end
```

Then in your controller, assign the Product's status as such

```
product_detail_status = Product.where(id:product_id).first
status = Status.where(name:status_name).first

product_detail_status.status = status
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, but am not sure its right way, on product model i remove

```
 include Mongoid::Versioning
```

by that i can save it on product model by command save.